# Javascript/Typescript - Extend Date object with new method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extend the Date object to add useful methods.

[According to W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_date.asp), this should work:

```
Date.prototype.removeTime = () => {
    // some awesome code to remove the timestamp
}
```

But Typescript complains that `removeTime` is not a known property of the `Date` object. (It is technically right)

So, I tried this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, "removeTime", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
        // Do some magic
        return null;
    }
});
```

But again, when using it in the code:

> Property 'removeTime' does not exist on type 'Date'

I don't understand because I did that to add a method to the array prototype, like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "unique", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
        const a = this.concat();
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
                if (a[i] === a[j]) {
                    a.splice(j--, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
});
```

And this works, I can use it in the code and Typescript doesn't complain.

What am I missing here ? Why does it work for `Array` and not with `Date` ?

EDIT:
After reading the comments, I decided to go with a method approach:

```
removeTimeFromDate(date: Date): Date {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay());
}
```

Comment: This is a really really bad idea to modify the built-in types. You better create a function that accepts a date object and returns a new date object.

Comment: *And this works, I can use it in the code and Typescript doesn't complain* Doesn't work for me, I get `Property 'unique' does not exist on type 'number[]'`. I don't think TS can automatically infer it (either correctly or at all), since the added property isn't static, but added at a specific point in runtime.

Comment: *"According to W3Schools, this should work"* Ugh, yet another example of w3schools getting it wrong. In two different ways no less.

Comment: [Array property doesn't work for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: From W3Schools: "*Date.prototype does not refer to a single date object, but to the Date() object itself.*" that...is quite wrong. The wording is weird but any of the multiple plausible readings I have on it are all the same - either it makes no sense because that's not how it works, or it simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: From W3Schools: "*Prototype is a global object constructor which is available for all JavaScript objects.*" I can't tell if this is wrong or somebody tries to twist words to make it sort of correct. Weirdly appropriate for the name of the website, I suppose - it sounds like a student is examined. They don't actually know the answer but try to use vague wording to not outright say the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things here:

1. Adding the runtime method
2. Adding the type information

What you're doing is adding the runtime thing, but you're not updating the type.

You can add the type information like this:

```
interface Date {
    removeTime(): Date;
}
```

That adds to the `Date` interface.

(Also, when adding the runtime method, use the `defineProperty` approach, not the assignment with arrow function.)

Here's a full example:

```
// Type
interface Date {
    removeTime(): Date;
}

// Runtime
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, "removeTime", {
    enumerable: false,   // This is the default, you can leave it off if you like
    configurable: true,  // Normally, method properties are configurable
    writable: true,      // Normally, method properties are writable
    value: function() {
        // Do some magic
        this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return this;
    }
});

let d = new Date();
console.log(d.toISOString());
d.removeTime();
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEBUE8AcFMCgCWA7ALrATgMwIYGNZQARHdUAb3lGtA1gFsB7AN1nEXtgAoBKALmKlYAbngBfePBCgASgFc0HBAHkARgCtYeVADoAJrCwpYABQyM4GVJC4l0O6OdSNrcADSgARHSat2nTw9KGlBYZDlODBxVABtYAVwYgGdYD2ppcAALRCTQHNBUTMIDXDkY1A9IRjlQPBxkUDicVjzUUEYsLDyuqpqYxABrBBC8RmQjAHM5KNj4gow5VPSwADlGDHocGJjID05Cxj1QRwtMVERYXJw6WrHJ6ei4qhoAdwxEVEe51AWlkNBpGsNlsdntYAcjidLOdLqBroQ3h8vs9qMwtosEgptIgxrwKCj-tIiIxQElGJxQJsJog8ASQoUcjoUqgABLVDBJLgABg8PNAfK5PFE-xodFQ0waDKSwpoEjEQskcTaRwAvKBkLAXoJ0LxRKNkGS4joYowJlw9DpnABJADKyhtPxQZp4CotPhYbCUuvg+sNsGNpvNlsYtvtjuQzqFQA)

---

FWIW, a couple of notes on extending builtins:

- It's generally not best practice in code that will be used in projects you don't directly control (library code you're writing to be used in other people's projects, etc.).
- It's generally best practice to use `defineProperty` to define a non-enumerable property (usually writable and configurable, though).
- Pick names that are really specific to your project, so that if the builtin is added to later in the specification, your name is unlikely to happen to get used. It's *just* possible a `removeTime` method might be added to `Date` at some point (though it's unlikely), but there's no chance an `myRemoveTime` method will be.

Comment: Why is it better to use the `defineProperty` approach? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnArcher - There are two different things wrong with the assignment-with-arrow-function in the OP's question: 1. Direct assignment creates an enumerable property. It's best not to have enumerable properties on prototype objects. With `defineProperty`, you can define a non-enumerable property. 2. An arrow function closes over `this` rather than having `this` set by how it's called, so it's not a good choice for methods, since methods need to have `this` set by how they're called. :-)